# Add a Report Menu item via code rather than Automation Steps

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add a report to the Reports menu of the SO Order Entry page via code rather than using Automation steps.  The code I am using is as follows but is producing the errors:
error CS0122: 'PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry.Report(PX.Data.PXAdapter, string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
error CS0119: 'PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry.Report(PX.Data.PXAdapter, string)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

```
public SOOrderEntry_Extension()
 {
    Base.Report.AddMenuAction(sOAcknowledgementReport);
 }

public PXAction<SOOrder> sOAcknowledgementReport;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "SO Acknowledgement Report")]
    protected void SOAcknowledgementReport()
       {
          if (Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr != string.Empty)
        {
           throw newPXReportRequiredException(Base.Document.Current, "SO641010", string.Empty);
        }
      }
```

Does anybody have suggestions how to add a Report to the reports menu via code rather than using Automation Steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can override Initialize() method and add the Report to report menu there. See the snippet code below on SOOrderEntry Graph Extension:

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{


    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Base.report.AddMenuAction(sOAcknowledgementReport);
    }


    public PXAction<SOOrder> sOAcknowledgementReport;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "SO Acknowledgement Report")]
    protected void SOAcknowledgementReport()
    {
        if (Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr != string.Empty)
        {
           throw new PXException("Test");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you want to perform the menu add in the Initialize call and use "report" vs "Report".

```
public override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();
    //Edit:  use report vs Report as HB_ACUMATICA mentioned
    Base.report.AddMenuAction(sOAcknowledgementReport);
}
```

Second, you will need to indicate the button as enabled by extending RowSelected. I think the automation stuff auto disables the button, so this is necessary to turn the button back using any condition you need to enable the button.

```
public virtual void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
{
    del?.Invoke(sender, e);
    sOAcknowledgementReport.SetEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: The "Report" identifier refers to the method definition, hence the error signature: PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry.Report(PX.Data.PXAdapter, string). Should be "report" referring to the action.

Comment: good catch @HB_ACUMATICA. Seems like a combo of not using initialize but also the error pointing out the incorrect use of the Action "report" vs "Report"